# Using induction to prove iterated supersets. I am wondering if my argument is correct

Tags: probability, induction

**Edit**: I have resubmitted the question here:
[Induction argument for proving set relations without using the induction hypothesis. Is my reasoning correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4066930/induction-argument-for-proving-set-relations-without-using-the-induction-hypothe)

It's almost 10 years since I completed a master's degree in mathematics, so I am a little rusty in writing proofs. I am working through a statistics text book to get some repetition.

I am doing some problems in the chapter on Probability and I have included my solution to one of the exercises. It seems correct to me, but from experience I know that is not always good enough! In short, is my reasoning for this proof correct?

[My induction argument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Okb9.png)

Since I am supposed to prove an infinite number of relationships, I immediately think of induction, but it looks like I don't really need the induction argument at all. Would it be enough to prove it for some arbitrary $m\in\mathbb{N}$?

Thanks for reading my question! Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: Better if you include everything here, rather than make users chase things offsite. If you have trouble typesetting math, there is help available via the Help menu.

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Okay, I will resubmit my question. I'll probably skip my life story as well. :)

Thanks for the feedback!